# Error while opening creating new Image Asset

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying to edit the logo of my Flutter application in Android Studio but when I try to open the Image Asset as follows but it throws an exception in the Android Support plugin.

[image: Screenshot of new Image Asset]

Is there any way to fix this issue?

[image: IDE Fatal Error]

Comment: I have already added the Assets like that. I'm trying to adjust the size and resolution of my app icon like this.

Comment: I have added project assets as per the documentation. Currently, I am trying to edit the App Icon through Image Asset Creation as it is not a perfect fit along with the icon borders. 

Image Creation tool helps me adjust all the icons (i.e. mipmap-hdpi, mipmap-mdpi, mipmap-xhdpi, etc.) at the same time.

Comment: I am loading them by defining my assets in pubspec.yaml file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a known issue with the flutter project setup.

To be able to use the Image Asset feature, open the Android project separately with Android Studio. Create/Edit your icon using the Image Asset feature. That should work.

**Update:** In your Flutter project folder, there is "android" folder. Open this folder in Android Studio by choosing the "Open existing project" dialog. Wait for the sync and build to complete. You can then use the Image Asset to change your app icon.

Comment: Can you please explain a little further because this is what I did.

Comment: Thanks for the Update. 
I tried that option as well but when I do that, the option for Image Asset disappears.

Comment: It should appear after the Android Studio's processing(Gradle Sync) is finished.

Comment: Thank you. I'll let you know as soon as it completes.

Comment: I don't think OP is asking about flutter assets. As I understand, he is asking about how to use the Image Asset feature of Android studio to create app icons for Android.